# Import statements code error

Tags: java

Okay, first the project I am working on has two packages, first is murach.business which contains invoiceCalculations.java
Second is murach.forms which contain InvoiceForm.java(JFrame) and SwingValidator.java

So, I am supposed to add Add import statements for the murach.business.InvoiceCalculations and java.text.NumberFormat classes in Invoiceformjava that i created from the scratch.

But, I am getting errors when i code that. netbeans says unused code.

Is my code incorrect? whats wrong? Please push in right direction.

```
/*
  * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

 package murach.forms;
 import murach.business.InvoiceCalculations;
 import java.text.NumberFormat;


 /**
   *
   * @author james
   */
 public class InvoiceForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form InvoiceForm
 */
public InvoiceForm() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    messageLabe1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    messageLabe2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    messageLabe3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    messageLabe4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    messageLabe5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    customertypeTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    subtotalTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    discountpercentTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    discountamountTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    totalTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    calculateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Invoice Total Calculator");

    messageLabe1.setText("Customer Type:");

    messageLabe2.setText("Subtotal:");

    messageLabe3.setText("Discount Percent:");

    messageLabe4.setText("Discount Amount:");

    messageLabe5.setText("Total:");

    customertypeTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            customertypeTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    subtotalTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            subtotalTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    discountpercentTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            discountpercentTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    calculateButton.setMnemonic('c');
    calculateButton.setText("Calculate");
    calculateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            calculateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    exitButton.setMnemonic('x');
    exitButton.setText("Exit");
    exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(38, 38, 38)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(messageLabe1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(messageLabe2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(messageLabe3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(messageLabe4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(messageLabe5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                    .add(totalTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 145, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .add(discountamountTextField))
                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, discountpercentTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(customertypeTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(subtotalTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(74, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .add(calculateButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(exitButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .add(43, 43, 43))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(31, 31, 31)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(messageLabe1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(customertypeTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(messageLabe2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(subtotalTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .add(6, 6, 6)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(messageLabe3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(discountpercentTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .add(6, 6, 6)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(messageLabe4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(discountamountTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .add(6, 6, 6)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(messageLabe5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(totalTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .add(18, 18, 18)
            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                .add(exitButton)
                .add(calculateButton))
            .addContainerGap(58, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void customertypeTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}                                                     

private void subtotalTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                 

private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
       // TODO add your handling code here:
    exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
        @Override
           public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
               exitButtonActionPerformed (evt);
           }
    });
}                                          

private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
      // TODO add your handling code here:
   double c = Double.parseDouble(customertypeTextField.getText());
   double s = Double.parseDouble(subtotalTextField.getText());
   double d = Double.parseDouble(discountpercentTextField.getText());

}                                               

private void discountpercentTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}                                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InvoiceForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InvoiceForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InvoiceForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InvoiceForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            InvoiceForm frame  =new InvoiceForm();
            frame.setVisible (true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton calculateButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField customertypeTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField discountamountTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField discountpercentTextField;
private javax.swing.JButton exitButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel messageLabe1;
private javax.swing.JLabel messageLabe2;
private javax.swing.JLabel messageLabe3;
private javax.swing.JLabel messageLabe4;
private javax.swing.JLabel messageLabe5;
private javax.swing.JTextField subtotalTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField totalTextField;
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

Comment: Unused code generally means you have some code after a return/break that will never get run. I'm not seeing it right off the bat. What line is it complaining about?

Comment: 2nd line from the top under the package.

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually using NumberFormat, but you are importing it.  There is no reason to import it if you're not actually going to use it directly in this class.